# What are the algorithms used to convert HTTP content to TEXT in clipboard?

Tags: html, winapi, browser, text, clipboard

I noticed that if you copy-paste web browser content into Notepad (or any text editor), you get different results, depending on the browser used.

That is, if you try the following:

1. Ctrl-A (while inside IE, Firefox,
   Chrome, etc.)
2. Ctrl-C
3. Ctrl-V (inside Notepad)

You will see that the text content from Internet Explorer is different than the one from Firefox.

(I conducted this test on Windows XP and Windows 7)

Why is that?

Are web browsers free to use any algorithm they choose to convert HTML content to CF_TEXT?

If so, are there any "minimal rules" they must adhere to?

Comment: I don't think cut&paste between "incompatible" (e.g. browser -> plaintext) environments is covered in any W3C specification, which'd mean that each browser can implement the feature however they want.

Comment: When you say 'HTML' are you asking about rendered content, or about the page source?

Comment: @Trevor you asked an excellent question: When I do Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C on a web page, it usually contains more than just "pure HTML". It contains Javascript, Flash and other stuff, **in addition** to HTML. So, I believe I am referring to **rendered content**.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks for clarifying this. Do you happen to know how this conversion (browser -> plaintext) takes place? For the sake of focus, let's assume we are in the Win32 API realm, e.g. GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT).

Comment: Stuff on the clipboard retains links back to where it came from (so you can do 'Paste Special' and the like in applications), so I'm guessing the browser handles the actual conversion. The copied text certainly isn't going onto the clipboard already as plain text in the first place.

Comment: @Marc B I think you are correct regarding the browser handles the actual conversion. In Windows, however, I believe that means that the copied text **is** going onto the clipboard already as plain text in the first place. Which means the browser has to issue multiple SetClipboardData() calls, each for every format supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649051%28v=VS.85%29.aspx Please correct if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Eternal: I don't know enough about windows internals to say for sure, but seems like a waste of cpu cycles, since you have no idea what the clipboard's going to be pasted into. could be notepad (plaintext), excel (grid/table table), word (rtf/formatted text), etc... Having to generate each format for every copy operation would be a heavy burden. At paste time, however, nothing says the past event can't trickle back to the browser which would do the appropriate conversion then.

Comment: @Eternal You're mistaken. Marc B is correct. Although an application MAY push the copied text immediately, it also has the option of telling the clipboard 1) that the user copied something, and 2) a list of formats that the data could be converted to. The actual conversion is deferred until a call is made to retrieve the clipboard data.

Comment: @Jon "The actual conversion is deferred until a call is made to retrieve the clipboard data." -- this is the clarification I needed to understand what's going on. Thank you! Please post a complete answer separately so that I can accept it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy data from the browser, the browser is responsible for converting data into the various clipboard formats. Since all of these data conversions can be expensive, most browsers will defer the conversion until a call is made to retrieve the clipboard data. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649051%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), this is accomplished by calling SetClipboardData with a NULL for the second parameter. When a later call is made to GetClipboardData, the browser receives a WM_RENDERFORMAT or WM_RENDERALLFORMATS message. It is at this point that the browser performs the conversion to text. There are no particular rules that the browser must follow when performing this conversion.

Comment: Wow, that's an excellent and very educating answer. Thank you!